# Transcode and generate thumbnails with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Using ffmpeg, and assuming it's doable, how can I transform input video from one format to another (e.g. MPEG-2 to MPEG-4) and generate thumbnails every *n* seconds at the same time?

Regards,
Matt

Comment: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs

Answer (score 2):

This command will take in.flv and transcode to .webm and .mp4 while simultaneously generating a single thumbnail.

```
ffmpeg -y -threads '1' -i 'in.flv' \
  -map '0:v' -map '0:a' -c:v 'libx264' -c:a 'libvo_aacenc' out.mp4 \
  -map '0:v' -map '0:a' -c:v 'libvpx' -c:a 'libvorbis' out.webm \
  -map '0:v' -r '1' -t '1' 'out.png'
```

To generate a thumbnail every n seconds, change -r (the frame-rate) to the inverse of n and remove -t (so that thumbnails are taken until the end of the video). For example, to generate a thumbnail every 4 seconds, you want a framerate of 1/4.

```
ffmpeg -y -threads '1' -i 'in.flv' \
  -map '0:v' -map '0:a' -c:v 'libx264' -c:a 'libvo_aacenc' out.mp4 \
  -map '0:v' -map '0:a' -c:v 'libvpx' -c:a 'libvorbis' out.webm \
  -map '0:v' -r '1/4' 'out-%d.png'
```

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at gstreamer, you can access data at each stage of the pipe. So to convert MPEG-4 to MPEG-2 , you do

```
filesrc | decodebin | tee | jpegencode | filesink(thumbnail) tee | mpeg2enocde | filesink(mpeg2 file)
```

Please lookup exact elements of gstreamer pipeline.